# Debian boot time, missing firmware

Tags: debian, hardware, firmware

I m using debian 9 stretch

When my debian boots, a long list of lines, many say firmware missing, many other error. Why these error are coming at first place?

My booting message are following:

```
[    0.296164] ACPI: \: Used as first EC

[    0.296164] ACPI: \: GPE=0x50, EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62

[    0.296164] ACPI: \: Used as boot ECDT EC to handle transactions

[    0.319283] **

ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.RP01.PXSX], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180810/psargs-330)



[    0.319292] ACPI Error: Ignore error and continue table load (20180810/psobject-604)

[    0.319296] ACPI Error: Skipping While/If block (20180810/psloop-623)

[    0.342435] ACPI: 9 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded

[    0.349815] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

[    0.356999] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:


--------------------------------------------------------------------------

[    1.186255] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp


--------------------------------------------------------------------------



[    9.411613] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input14

[    9.413574] pstore: Registered efi as persistent store backend

[    9.435506] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80

[    9.435603] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80

[    9.461380] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 5 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer

[    9.461382] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules

--------------------------------------------------------------------------


[   11.451232] bluetooth hci0: firmware: **failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin (-2)**

[   11.451238] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2

[   11.451269] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 22496


[   11.464392] rtl8723be 0000:03:00.0: firmware: **failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin (-2)**

[   11.464399] rtl8723be 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin failed with error -2

[   11.481313] rtl8723be 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin

[   11.481320] rtlwifi: Loading alternative firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

[   12.307182] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: **NVIDIA GM108 (1180e0a2)**
```

Can I install Nvidia driver non-free? How can I do that? I have nvidia GTX 930mx.

```
[   12.331549] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 82.08.59.00.29

[   12.403513] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC255: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker

[   12.403515] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)

[   12.403517] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)

[   12.403517] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0

[   12.403518] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:

[   12.403520] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x1b

[   12.403521] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19

[   12.416140] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 2048 MiB DDR3


[   12.416160] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]

[   12.432301] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 10ac08 [ IBUS ]

[   12.492688] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)

[   12.519082] dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system

[   12.599606] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Failed to find dell wmi symbol dell_micmute_led_set

[   12.655743] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS

[   12.655972] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------


[   13.713693] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB


[   13.713696] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table invalid

[   13.713722] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0

[   13.714544] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

[   41.358571] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized

[   41.358576] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized

[   41.358580] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

[   58.364851] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]

[   62.269020] fuse init (API version 7.27)

[  170.939363] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
```